# How to add strongly typed field in Formik by typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I tried to add strongly typed in Formik react library by typescript, but I didn't do that. Of course, I have used this link, but I couldn't solve my issue.
https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/typescript

I have got this error from this part of code(})(ActivityForm);):

> Argument of type '(props: IProps) => Element' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'CompositeComponent
>   & FormikState & FormikHelpers & FormikHandlers & FormikComputedProps &
>   FormikRegistration & { ...; }>'. Type '(props: IProps) => Element' is
>   not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent & FormikState & FormikHelpers & FormikHandlers
>   & FormikComputedProps & FormikRegistration & { ...; }>'. Types of
>   parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible. Property
>   'setEditMode' is missing in type 'FormikSharedConfig<{}> & FormikState
>   & FormikHelpers & FormikHandlers & FormikComputedProps &
>   FormikRegistration & { ...; } & { ...; }' but required in type
>   'IProps'.ts(2345) ActivityForm.tsx(7, 3): 'setEditMode' is declared
>   here.

---

> const ActivityForm: React.FunctionComponent Argument of type
>   'FunctionComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'CompositeComponent &
>   FormikState & FormikHelpers &
>   FormikHandlers & FormikComputedProps &
>   FormikRegistration & { ...; }>'.   Type 'FunctionComponent' is
>   not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent & FormikState &
>   FormikHelpers & FormikHandlers &
>   FormikComputedProps & FormikRegistration & { ...; }>'.
>       Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
>         Type 'WeakValidationMap | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap &
>   FormikState & FormikHelpers &
>   FormikHandlers & FormikComputedProps &
>   FormikRegistration & { ...; }> | undefined'.
>           Type 'WeakValidationMap' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap &
>   FormikState & FormikHelpers &
>   FormikHandlers & FormikComputedProps &
>   FormikRegistration & { ...; }>'.
>             Types of property 'setFormikState' are incompatible.
>               Type 'Validator<(f: FormikState | ((prevState: FormikState) => FormikState),
>   cb?: (() => void) | undefined) => void> | undefined' is not assignable
>   to type 'Validator<(f: FormikState | ((prevState:
>   FormikState) => FormikState), cb?: (() =>
>   void) | undefined) => void> | undefined'.
>                 Type 'Validator<(f: FormikState | ((prevState: FormikState) => FormikState),
>   cb?: (() => void) | undefined) => void>' is not assignable to type
>   'Validator<(f: FormikState | ((prevState:
>   FormikState) => FormikState), cb?: (() =>
>   void) | undefined) => void>'.
>                   Type '(f: FormikState | ((prevState: FormikState) => FormikState), cb?: (() =>
>   void) | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(f:
>   FormikState | ((prevState: FormikState) =>
>   FormikState), cb?: (() => void) | undefined) => void'.
>                     Types of parameters 'f' and 'f' are incompatible.
>                       Type 'FormikState | ((prevState: FormikState) => FormikState)' is not
>   assignable to type 'FormikState | ((prevState:
>   FormikState) => FormikState)'.
>                         Type 'FormikState' is not assignable to type 'FormikState | ((prevState:
>   FormikState) => FormikState)'.
>                           Type 'FormikState' is not assignable to type 'FormikState'.ts(2345) Peek Problem
>   No quick fixes available

---

**this error comes from ActivityDashboard.tsx**

> Type '{ setEditMode: (editMode: boolean) => void; title: string;
>   description: string; category: string; city: string; venue: string;
>   date: string; }' is missing the following properties from type
>   'IProps': values, errors, touched, isSubmitting, and 28 more.ts(2740)

---

```
import React from "react";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { withFormik, Form, Field, FormikProps } from "formik";


interface IProps {
  setEditMode: (editMode: boolean) => void;
}

export const ActivityForm = (props: IProps) => {
  const { setEditMode } = props;
  return (
    <Form>
      <Field type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
      <Field
        type="text"
        rows={2}
        name="description"
        placeholder="Description"
      />
      <Field type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category" />
      <Field type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date" />
      <Field type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" />
      <Field type="text" name="venue" placeholder="Venue" />
      <button type="submit">Edit</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setEditMode(false)}>
        Cancel
      </button>
    </Form>
  );
};

const myForm = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: props => {
    return {};
  },
  validationSchema: yup.object().shape({
    title: yup.string().required()
  }),
  handleSubmit(values) {
    console.log(values);
  }
})(ActivityForm);

export default myForm;
```

---

```
import React from "react";
import { IActivity } from "../../../app/models/activity";
import { ActivityList } from "./ActivityList";
import { Col, Row } from "antd";
import { ActivityDetails } from "../details/ActivityDetails";
import { ActivityForm } from "../form/ActivityForm";

interface IProps {
  activities: IActivity[];
  selectActivity: (id: string) => void;
  selectedActivity: IActivity | null;
  editMode: boolean;
  setEditMode: (editMode: boolean) => void;
  setSelectedActivity: (activity: IActivity | null) => void;
}

export const ActivityDashboard: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  activities,
  selectActivity,
  selectedActivity,
  editMode,
  setEditMode,
  setSelectedActivity
}) => {
  return (
    <Row>
      <Col span={3}></Col>
      <Col span={10}>
        <ActivityList activities={activities} selectActivity={selectActivity} />
      </Col>
      <Col span={1}></Col>
      <Col span={6}>
        {selectedActivity && !editMode && (
          <ActivityDetails
            activity={selectedActivity}
            setEditMode={setEditMode}
            setSelectedActivity={setSelectedActivity}
          />
        )}
        {editMode && (
          <ActivityForm
            setEditMode={setEditMode}
            title="alex"
            description="hi"
            category="human"
            city="newyork"
            venue="sd"
            date="2019"
          />
        )}
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are multiple issues here which causes the confusing message from the TypeScript compiler:

1. First of all, make sure that your functional component extends the `React.FC<Props>` type so that TypeScript knows that this is a React component:

   ```
   import * as React from 'react';

   export const ActivityForm : React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
   ...
   ```
2. Then you have to extend your `IProps`-type with the `FormikProps`-type from the `formik` package, because the `withFormik`-method only accepts React-components whose props are extend from this type:

   ```
   import { FormikProps } from 'formik';

   interface MyFormValues {
     title: string;
     category: string;
     description: string;
   }

   interface IProps extends FormikProps<MyFormValues> {
     setEditMode(arg: boolean): void;
   }
   ```

Your final code should then look like this (Make sure to add the missing properties to the `MyFormValues` interface):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withFormik, Form, Field, FormikProps } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

interface MyFormValues {
  title: string;
  category: string;
  description: string;
  ...
}

interface IProps extends FormikProps<MyFormValues> {
  setEditMode(arg: boolean): void;
}

export const ActivityForm: React.FC<IProps> = props => {
  const { setEditMode } = props;
  return (
    <Form>
      <Field type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
      <Field
        type="text"
        rows={2}
        name="description"
        placeholder="Description"
      />
      <Field type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category" />
      <Field type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date" />
      <Field type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" />
      <Field type="text" name="venue" placeholder="Venue" />
      <button type="submit">Edit</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setEditMode(false)}>
        Cancel
      </button>
    </Form>
  );
};

const myForm = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: props => {
    return {};
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string().required()
  }),
  handleSubmit(values) {
    console.log(values);
  }
})(ActivityForm);

export default myForm;
```

Also here is a CodeSandbox with the final code: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow59057524-s9ouc?module=%2Fsrc%2FActivityForm.tsx