# Use Formik with React.FC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I have a form that's set-up as a function component in React where the forms values are managed by the state hook. I want to add Formik to this however when I set-up the enhanced form I get this error:

```
Argument of Type FC<Props> is not assignable to parameter of type 'CompositeComponent<FormikSharedConfig & FormikState<{}> & FormikActions<{}> & FormikHandlers & FormikComputedProps<{}> & FormikRegistration>
```

The component has it's set-up something like

```
const Form: React.FC<Props> = () => {
    [formVal, setFormVal] = React.useState<string>('')
    [formValTwo, setFormValTwo] = React.useState<string>('')

    // some functions related to managing the form
    return (
       <>
         // render form
       </>
    )
}

const EnhancedForm = withFormik ({
    mapPropsToValues: () => ({...props})

    handleSubmit:(values, {setSubmitting}) => {...}

})(EnhancedForm) // above error shows here
```

Am I using Formik wrong? if so how would I do form management for React.FC?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057524/how-to-add-strongly-typed-field-in-formik-by-typescript

Comment: So I tried this but I get this error when I create an interface for the Form values (called FormValues), 'interface FormProps extends FormikProps<FormValues>, Props{}' and then my component const form = React.FC<FormProps> = ({ formValue }) => {...}, here formValue isn't found it tells me proprty formValue does not exist on FormProps...Even though I've extended FormProps with the FormValues

Comment: could you create an example in sandbox?

Comment: `useFormik` hook?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `Props` ?

In your code snippet, why are you doing:

```
const EnhancedForm = withFormik ({
    mapPropsToValues: () => ({...props})

    handleSubmit:(values, {setSubmitting}) => {...}

})(EnhancedForm) // above error shows here
```

instead of:

```
const EnhancedForm = withFormik ({
    mapPropsToValues: () => ({...props})

    handleSubmit:(values, {setSubmitting}) => {...}

})(Form) // above error shows here
```

Maybe you can try this:

```
import { InjectedFormikProps } from 'formik';

interface FormValues {
  // The values of your form
  // email: string;
  // password: string;
}

interface Props {
  // your props
}

const Form: React.FC<InjectedFormikProps<Props, FormValues>> = () => {
    [formVal, setFormVal] = React.useState<string>('')
    [formValTwo, setFormValTwo] = React.useState<string>('')

    // some functions related to managing the form
    return (
       <>
         // render form
       </>
    )
}

const EnhancedForm = withFormik ({
    mapPropsToValues: () => ({...props})

    handleSubmit:(values, {setSubmitting}) => {...}

})(Form) // above error shows here
```

This way you can tell Typescript your `Form` component accepts Formik related props. Because there is no way for Typescript to know this.